# how is an event triggered for a service in oracle brm

Tags: oracle-apps

Hello every one i have been going through the oracle communications business revenue management (BRM)   docs for sometime now but one thing i can't figure out is how are the events associated with a service triggered actually. Is it done by the BRM or the client application interacting with the BRM. Somehow the docs don't mention it or i may have missed it.Would be nice if someone can explain it to me. Note the term service is used in the same context as used in BRM docs i.e. something that the customers subscribe to and pay for when use i.e. telephony service. the link to the docs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51000_01/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are created by BRM:

- the logic is defined in the CM (Connection Manager) tier, inside the Facilities Modules (FMs)
- the actual SQL instructions are generated by the Oracle DM (`dm_oracle`)

For the sake of completeness, there is also another way in which events are created:

- Call Detail Records (CDRs) are rated with the Batch Rating Engine (Pipeline Manager) and generate Rated Event records
- these are then loaded, via the Rated Event Loader (REL), directly to the database. Under the hood, REL calls SQL*Loader and a stored procedure to update account balances and bill items